# How to import classes from within another directory / package

Tags: java, directory, package

I am working on a somewhat large project with many subdirectories. I am, however, coming across an issue of importing classes from within another directory. The directory structure is as so:

```
main.dir
   repository.dir
      Bill.java
   transaction.dir
      AutomaticBillPay.java
```

How can I import `Bill` into `AutomaticBillPay`?

I have tried may iterations of:

```
package main;
package main.repositorysys;

import main.repositorysys.Bill;
import repositorysys.Bill;
import Bill;
```

Sadly, the only line that compiles is the first: `package main;`. Any tips / direction will help!

Comment: You cannot have dots in the directory names if you want them to be part of your Java package structure. Rename main.dir -> `main`, transaction.dir -> `transaction`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it through this

```
    /*Declare your class package */
    package main.transactionsubsys;

    /*import the classes you want */
    import main.repositorysys.Bill;

    /*Write your class*/
    public class AutomaticBillPay {

    /*AutomaticBillPay code */

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AutomaticBillPay` should look like this:

```
package main.transaction;

import main.repository.Bill;

public class AutomaticBillPay {
    // your class implementation here
}
```

Not sure where `repositorysys` came from?

`package` should be the full path to your encompassing directory

`import` should be the full path to the class you want to import